# Not able to search a div element using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```html
<div class="panel-menu-container dropdown open">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--menu panel-menu" role="menu">
      <li>
         <a>
            <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-uasfgx"></svg>
            </div>
            <span class="dropdown-item-text" aria-label="Panel header item View">View</span>
            <span class="dropdown-menu-item-shortcut">
               <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-uasfgx"></svg>
               </div>
               v
            </span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a>
            <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-uasfgx"></svg>
            </div>
            <span class="dropdown-item-text" aria-label="Panel header item Share">Share</span>
            <span class="dropdown-menu-item-shortcut">
               <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-uasfgx"></svg>
               </div>
               p s
            </span>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-right">
         <a>
            <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
               <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-uasfgx"></svg>
            </div>
            <span class="dropdown-item-text" aria-label="Panel header item Inspect">
               Inspect
               <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-sys05s"></svg>
               </div>
            </span>
            <span class="dropdown-menu-item-shortcut">
               <div class="css-wf08df-Icon">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" class="css-uasfgx"></svg>
               </div>
               i
            </span>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu--menu panel-menu" role="">
            <li><a><span class="dropdown-item-text" aria-label="Panel header item Data">Data</span></a></li>
            <li><a><span class="dropdown-item-text" aria-label="Panel header item Panel JSON">Panel JSON</span></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to click on **Data** as shown in the pic [image].
The HTML code above contains the code for this list.

I am not able to search/find main menu by using :

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"panel-menu-container dropdown open")

and getting error [image]
Kindly help me out.

```
def scrape_data():
    DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\chrome\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH)
    driver.get('Link to the dashboard')
    time.sleep(20)    
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='panel-menu-container dropdown open']")
```

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Looks like you need first to click on "Inspect" because if not data will not be shown. Did you try first to click on "Inspect" element? Please share the code you tried.

Comment: @JakyRuby this is private grafana dashboard, I can't share the URL.

Comment: @JakyRuby yes thank you I needed to click on "Inspect". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to click the parent `div` element with class name values `panel-menu-container dropdown open` this can be done with following XPath or CSS Selector.
It should not be done by `CLASS_NAME` since `CLASS_NAME` accepts single class name value while this element contains 3 class name values: `panel-menu-container` `dropdown` `open`
So, with CSS Selector:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".panel-menu-container.dropdown.open")
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.panel-menu-container.dropdown.open")
```

With XPath:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@class='panel-menu-container dropdown open']")
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='panel-menu-container dropdown open']")
```

In case you want to click the `Data` option this XPath should work:

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Data')]")
```

In case you prefer CSS Selectors - this can also be done by CSS Selector:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label='Panel header item Data']")
```

Or

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[aria-label='Panel header item Data']")
```

Comment: This doesn't work I am still getting selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException error.

Comment: Very strange. Can you share a link to the page you working on?

Comment: It is a private grafana dashboard.

Comment: OK,, let's try some blind debugging. What element are you failing to find?

Comment: I am able to do so now. The problem was that this list is visible on a button click and I had not clicked the button so it was not visible. Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: Sure. I have upvoted the answer.